# How to show content without featured image

Tags: wordpress

I have add a new post from admin panel of wordpress and the post is showing on home page.when I have added the featured image of the post then post is coming with full content means post title, post description, read more and featured image.
but when I have add post without featured image then the it is showing me only description of the post without title,read more button.

So please help me how can i show post content,excerpt and date etc of post without featured image.

Comment: for title i have add this <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1> Any one can help me

Comment: you want not to show featured image any where on your site or only on home page?

Answer (score 0):

Used as a replacement for the_content() to force excerpts to show within The Loop.

```
     <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

//inside brackets you can give limit for exerpt

for date you can use within loop

```
  <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?>
```

Comment: to hide featured image you can use. .thumbnail-div {
     display:none;
}

Comment: how can i add leave comment tag bottom of the post content

Comment: @indresh you can add comment box by going to settings in admin panel enable the comments....and then write <?php comments_template(); ?> where you want to show it.....please accept the above ans i think your question is answered